# How can I move this Python object into C++ using ctypes?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

This is a smaller part of a larger problem but I have a C++ class that I am initializing in python and when I try to pass the object back to C++ from python, none of the initialized values make the transition.

The original class is from C++ and it is initialized in Python and the problem comes when I try to move the initialized object back to C++.

Python Code

```
from ctypes import c_int, c_double, CDLL, Structure


lib = CDLL('./libDftConfig.so')

class Atom(Structure):
  _fields_ = [('type_', c_int), ('x_', c_double), 
              ('y_', c_double), ('z_', c_double)]

  # Using C++ class 
  def __init__(self, t, x, y, z):
    self.obj = lib.Atom_init(t, x, y, z)


def wrap_function(lib, funcname, restype, argtypes):
  func = lib.__getattr__(funcname)
  func.restype = restype
  func.argtypes = argtypes
  return func

# wrap the C++ function
print_atom = wrap_function(lib, 'py_print_atom', None, [Atom]) 

# Initialize C++ class and pass it back to C++ here
print_atom(Atom(50,5,10,15))
```

C++ Code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Atom {
public:
    Atom(int type, double x, double y, double z) : type_(type), x_(x), y_(y), z_(z) {}  
    int     type_;
    double  x_;
    double  y_;
    double  z_;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &strm, const Atom &atom) {
    return strm << atom.type_ << " " << atom.x_ << " " << atom.y_ << " " << atom.z_ << std::endl;
}

void print_atom(Atom atom)
{
  std::cout << atom << std::endl;
}

extern "C"
{
  Atom* Atom_init(int type, double x, double y, double z)
  {
    return new Atom(type, x, y, z);
  }
  void py_print_atom(Atom atom){print_atom(atom);}
}
```

Expecting: 50 5 10 15
Actual: 0 0 0 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure i will give you the best answer, and i don't check it (it is just by experience).

First i would write the return type of Atom Init, just to be sure.

```
lib.Atom_init.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
```

Then i would write in the C++ code where there is the externalization

```
void py_print_atom(Atom * atom){print_atom(*atom);}
```

And finish by changing the python code.

```
print_atom = wrap_function(lib, 'py_print_atom', None, [ctypes.c_void_p])
```

In this way i am quite sure it would work. This is how i externalize my C++ function. If you don't want to do it by hands you can also use Boost::Python (but i guess you knew it :D).

Hoping it helps you.

Comment: I got the following error after making the suggested changes :     "    print_atom(Atom(50,5,10,15))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: wrong type
" but it gave me an idea that I will try later. Thank you.